# Content Server for SAP ArchiveLink Error Server Status

Tags: sap-basis, dms

I am Integrating SAP to DMS(M-files). During Installation of Content Server I faced following issue
ContentServer: "4.3.0 P2 C20150314"

ServerStatus: "error"

ServerVendorId: "null null"

ServerTime: "05:59:22"

ServerDate: "2021-03-27"

ServerVersion: "null"

ProtocolVersion: "0047"

No or invalid License installed -> please request for a valid license (SiteCode >>313934DC2<<)

No Connection to DMS could be made -> please check that vendor specific SAPALINK files are installed correctly and/or DMS is up and running!

ContentServer's security not installed correctly -> please check security librarys and/or Init params (PABName, PABPassword)

Error Look like This

[This Is Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZ4T7.png)

Answer (score 0):

No Connection to DMS could be made -> please check that vendor specific SAPALINK files are installed correctly and/or DMS is up and running!
For this error, Please check that you are giving correct vault Id, username and password.

ContentServer's security not installed correctly -> please check security librarys and/or Init params (PABName, PABPassword).
For this error, try to set security = 1